# drupal---HOOK_theme() in template.php

Tags: templates, drupal, hook

could  i declare a HOOK_theme() in template.php,if can,how to declare it. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement hook_theme in the template.php file of your theme. See the [API documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme/6) for details.

Comment: i have read it,but still don't know how to use it. could you give me an example to explain it. thank you.

Comment: For an example, see how the node_example module implements hook_theme as the node_example_theme function (http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/node_example--node_example.module/function/node_example_theme/6). It simply defines a theme hook and the arguments that it can accept. Once the theme hook is defined, you can call `theme('node_example_order_info', $array)`. Your module can do the same.